# Upgrade React Native from 0.64.2 to latest

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I need to upgrade my React Native application to latest version

I tried to use the command `npx react-native upgrade` but I got an error:
[image]

`error Command failed: npm install --save --save-exact react-native@0.72.1 react@18.2.0`

And this is the report generated:
[image]

How can I solve it? I like to prevent also the --legacy-peer-deps after that porting

Comment: Could this be because that the dependency is not fully supported in the react native version you are downloading? I suggest that you go to the documentation for more information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have so many differences between your version and the lastest one. It is something that can not make with just a command.

Use this [tool](https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/?from=0.64.2&to=0.72.1) (upgrade-helper) to have a guide how to update your project and then you will need to fix your dependencies 1 by 1.

there is no short way, so take your time and be patient.